# conv.user.storage value not saving across sessions when invoking via speech

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to use the conv.user.storage to save information across sessions for my user, namely I want to give him an ID.

When I invoke my action via keyboard, it will save my user storage ID fine, and when I run the action again from my developer console, it will console.log the saved ID in the session. 
However, when I invoke the action via speech, it will not save the storage value for the next session.

```
const generateRandomId = require('uuid/v4');
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv) =>{

  if(conv.user.storage["id"] ==undefined){

    conv.user.storage.id = generateRandomId();
  }

  console.log(conv.user.storage.id);

conv.close(`your user id is ${conv.user.storage.id});
});
```

so this intent will generate a  new value every time for conv.user.storage.id when using the action via speech with my google home device, I want it to be the same every time, this is so I can save my user ID in the database to track their highscore.

**EDIT**

This is also occurs when I try to track the ID using conv.user.id, so when i use my action with keyboard it will always be the same ID of:

```
ABwppHGgFSnon5unUNjikof_5G-m_8lldEd_LIokoqYlOsCSFm96--UHDJ_GOHHo6hFOQUZVoMTT6TvfT_edklKbaPm
```

whereas the id which is produced by conv.user.id when using the app via speech is just a bunch of numbers like this:

```
1539765602273384238765
```

Comment: This looks similar to the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/q/52779281/1405634. We're still trying to reliably duplicate the problem, but at least some of us **have** been able to duplicate it.

Comment: Can you confirm *exactly* which version of the actions-on-google library you're using? (I don't think its an issue with the library, but there were changes in it recently related to user storage, so we want to rule it out.)

Comment: I am using `actions-on-google@2.3.0`

Comment: Try it again with `actions-on-google@2.4.1`, please. (Again, I don't think this is it, but let's make sure.)

Comment: I've just updated all my packages and the results are the same.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I have the same problem! For me it does not work even via keyboard. @Prisoner