# Actions-on-Google user.storage not saved on Dialogflow SDK

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've developing an action by using Dialogflow SDK and Firebase Functions. I'm using conv.user.storage to save user ID between conversations. However, every time user comes to action, Action can not recognize saved ID and shows it "undefined". I've been developing this action for a while and users that I created for test 2-3 months ago, have conv.user.storage and they can be recognized. Is there a limit for storing data or something else?

Here is my code:

```
if (!conv.user.storage.userId || typeof conv.user.storage.userId === "undefined") {
  conv.user.storage.userId = uuidv1();
  console.log("new implemented userID.", conv.user.storage.userId);
}
else {
  console.log("ID from storage", conv.user.storage.userId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this conv.user.storage does not work properly! It did not work for me even with the voice match and allowed privacy setting! You can also see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853576/conv-user-storage-value-not-saving-across-sessions-when-invoking-via-speech?noredirect=1&lq=1).
Google support suggested me to use Google account linking to get unique user id from the users and save it to the db. This is the documentation for account linking:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

Comment: Thanks @Frosty! I used same method. Yet, I still need some data to store. I'm in contact with support. I'll let you know if I get some useful help from support.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem as you.. I found the fix in this [comment](https://github.com/actions-on-google/codelabs-nodejs/issues/26#issuecomment-448519451) in a github issue. Basically when enabling the Web & App permissions in the Activity Center you need also to check " include chrome history .... "

Comment: Thanks! Yet, I am not the one facing this problem. The main issue here is users can not be recognized by application and how can I make them to check or change on their phone?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your workflow is not setup to allow for storing user data consistently. You can check the documentation on expiring the data.

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#user_storage_expiration

If you're using a smart speaker, ensure voice match is setup. And make sure you have all the necessary permissions turned on.

Comment: Hi Nick! I don't use smart speaker. And checked for user preferences to save data. What else may cause this problem, do you have any idea?